# I used to wget the "historical" from the original coinbase api - cant find it with v2 api

Tags: windows, http, wget, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I used to use a simple wget to https://api.coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/historical to get a file of past and current buy prices from coinbase on Bitcoin. Now with the new v2 API i am unable to find documentation to lead me to this file in the new system. Anyone know what i should do?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price has a section labeled ARGUMENTS that describes how you can add an argument. "Specify date for historic spot price in format YYYY-MM-DD (UTC)"

Alternatively, you can use this URL for historic prices within the last month: http://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/historic?period=month

Comment: That `period` query parameter seems to be undocumented. Or is it documented somewhere else? How did you learn of it? What are its valid arguments?

Comment: I found it through another comment on StackOverflow a few days ago, sadly I can't find it now. I also found this: https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=2018-01-10T12:00:00?stop=2019-04-15&12:00:00?granularity=900

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the documentation on this too. I've been trying the period query parameter in my application, passing a 'day' argument; it appears to kinda work ... but it seems there some inconsistency with the interval of spot prices returned, sometimes it returns a price record for every 5 minutes during the day, sometimes it's every 10 minutes. So far, I've been unable  to identify any reason for this or any pattern in its occurrence.